# What performance impact will usage of ELMAH cause?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I have a ASP.NET 4.0 web application and I intend to integrate ELMAH for error logging purposes. I am planning to store the error log in SQL Server.

But I can't find any blog or discussion on what performance impact it has. Can anybody share with me, any performance related issues, with the usage of ELMAH.

Answer (score 0):

We've used it for over a year with no performance implications that we've noticed.

The only thing we've experienced an issue with is the size of the logging table if you have lots of exceptions. The rows are quite 'wide' and the table can easily grow to several Gb if not monitored; we run a regular SQL job which removes older rows from the table to prevent it from growing too big. Of course, this only applies if you are logging to a DB.